# MySQL TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers

I cant get this to work, it runs OK, but nothing happens in insert

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT 
    ON prueba 
    FOR EACH ROW     
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.jo=1
    END
DELIMITER $$;
insert into prueba (ja) values (16);

CREATE TABLE `prueba` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ja` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `prueba` WRITE;
```

What im i doing wrong??

Comment: You are not using the `DELIMITER` correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154158/mysql-how-do-i-use-delimiters-in-triggers for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I have understood correct then what you are actually trying to achieve is to have a default value of `1` for the column `jo`. in such case no need of a `before insert trigger`. You can just define that as `default value` for that column while creating the table like

```
CREATE TABLE `prueba` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ja` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jo` int(11) DEFAULT 1, <-- Notice This Line
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then after insertion, you will have a record as

```
ID  JA  JO
1   16  1
```

See a demo [Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e828/1)

Talking about your create trigger syntax. Try the below modified trigger code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON prueba 
    FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN   
        SET NEW.jo=1;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i wasnt trying to put default values, it was just an example, my real goal is to transform date in diferent ways, like year, month, day of week, etc.